# TV pseudo-documentary featuring humans defending the Earth from a huge alien ship using manhole covers

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

What is the name of this TV pseudo-documentary? The only way to attack a huge alien ship hovering over the Earth is to set off nuclear weapons underground with manhole covers on top.  These are launched into space at the alien ship and tear holes in it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Plumbbob - Orbital manhole covers are a real thing

Comment: Sort of.  The cap on the bore hole was blown off. Exactly happened after the single image in which the cap appears is the subject of some debate.  If it were moving as fast as estimated, it may have burned up passing through the atmosphere.  If it were significantly slower  may have come back down somewhere.

Comment: It sounds so ridiculous that I almost accidentally downvoted your question instead of upvoting it.

Comment: I remember watching this, was Michio Kaku in it? I also remember the aliens attacked by causing tidal waves from orbital weapondry, and genetically modifying avian flu.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the Discovery Channel's "Curiosity", Season 1 Episode 2, "Alien Invasion, Are We Ready?", released in 2011. In the pseudo-documentary, Humans first try launching nukes directly, with little effect, then launch several
Operation Plumbbob style attacks at once, damaging the alien ship. The experts interviewed were David Bartell and Doug Beason. You can easily find it on dailymotion, but I can't link to it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(TV_series)

Comment: No, we ain't ready. If their goal was conquest, maybe we could resist. But if the aliens merely wanted to kill everyone, any tech that can propel spacecraft at a significant fraction of light speed only needs to send several manholes of their own at Earth, which as many videos have shown, would be more than enough to cause h-bomb-like devastation. It is the alien desire to leave the ecosystem intact that would be our leverage but I would still guess that they could use nanomachines or whatever to selectively kill or sicken human resisters.

Comment: @releseabe, this.  Any civilization that can send a populated vessel across the stars at relativistic speeds *AND STOP* upon arrival in a new system, has the power and technology to annihilate us when they get here should they so desire.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman. But not necessarily in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 13):

This sounds very similar to the premise of the comedy science fiction film *[Where The Aliens Are](https://wherethealiensare.com/)*:

> What if aliens suddenly arrived in orbit and turned off all electronic
> devices on Earth? A retired professor and his neighbors take matters
> into their own hands with a bold plan: detonate a nuclear bomb and
> hurl heavy objects at the alien spaceship. *Note:  The story  is based
> on the 1950s nuclear Project "Thunderwell."*

The screenplay has won a few awards, including *Best Comedy Feature Screenplay, American Filmatic Arts Awards (2021)*, and storyboard is available at the project's webpage, but I don't see any sign that a film or TV episode actually has actually been made from it.

Comment: That isn't a pseudodocumentary though

Comment: @qazwsx True. I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: All the safety devices in "nucular" bombs require electricity.